# Add span to side of center align element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement some designs in CSS, but having a bit of trouble figuring out how to align this `<span>` correctly.

I am trying to achieve the `<input>` and `<button>` elements being **centrally aligned**, but the `<span>` element being absolutely to the right of the `<input>`, example:

[image: Required Output]

It's important to make sure that the `<span>` does not affect the alignment of the other elements. The `<input>` and `<button>` *should always be exactly in the middle of the parent*.

Would be great if I could do this in CSS only. This is what I have so far:

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: #B7B7B7;
    width: 400px;
}
input {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: auto;
}
.verify {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* Not sure how to calculate these? */
    right: 0; /* Input.X + Input.Width + 15px ?? */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input placeholder="Enter code" maxlength="8" size="8"/><br />
    <span class="verify"></span>
    <button>Register</button>
</div>
```

Additional Info:

- It only has to work in Chrome
- I can make all elements a fixed width if required
- I can make DOM changes if required
- I would prefer not to hardcode X/Y co-ordinates for the `<span>`...I might want to change the input/button dimensions later

Comment: Can you wrap the `input` and `span` in an additional `div`?

Comment: @KilianStinson Sure. Don't mind DOM changes either

Comment: Simply wrap the input and your span in another outer span, and make the outer span positioned relative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the input and the span inside a div with `position: relative` and `display:inline`

The span `.verify` will get absolutely positioned, leaving the input element to it's original position (centered aligned)

By giving a `top:50%` and then `margin-top: -10px (half of its height)`, it will get in the middle of it's parent height.

```css
.wrp {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: #B7B7B7;
    width: 400px;
}
.inpWrp {
    display: inline;
    position:relative;
}
input {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: auto;
}
.verify {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -10px;
    top: 50%; /* Not sure how to calculate these? */
    right: -20px; /* Input.X + Input.Width + 15px ?? */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">

    <div class="inpWrp">
     <input placeholder="Enter code" maxlength="8" size="8"/>
     <span class="verify"></span>
    </div>        
    <br />
    <button>Register</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nearly perfect! I had to remove the whitespace between `input` and `span.verify` and add `5px` to the `right` value because the center alignment was off by 5px

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your input element in `span` and using pseudo-element `:after` to create the square. No need of position absolute:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #B7B7B7;
  width: 400px;
}
input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.verify:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="verify">
    <input placeholder="Enter code" maxlength="8" size="8"/>
    </span>
  <br />
  <button>Register</button>
</div>
```

After @kapantzak comment you can use position absolute like:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #B7B7B7;
  width: 400px;
}
input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: auto;
}
.verify:after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="verify">
    <input placeholder="Enter code" maxlength="8" size="8"/>
    </span>
  <br />
  <button>Register</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Good thinking! But the input is getting pushed a bit to the left because of the new content

Comment: @kapantzak Thanks for the feedback. Add a second version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
.main_container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: #B7B7B7;
    width: 400px;
}
input {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: auto;
}
.verify {
    display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
    <div><input placeholder="Enter code" maxlength="8" size="8"/>
        <span class="verify"></span></div>
    <button>Register</button>
</div>
```